# Написать функцию, которая находит все элементы в массиве символов, не равных указанному символу

Tags: c

Я написала код, который на `с++` работает, но когда перевожу на `С`, то перестает. Он почему-то не может считать символ, который нужно удалить и закрывает программу. Можете помочь?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
char A[100];
int n , i;
char ch;
printf("razmer ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("symbol ");

for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
  scanf("%s", &A[i]);
}
for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
  printf("%2c", A[i]);
}
printf("\ndelite ");
scanf("%s", &ch);
printf("\n");
for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
    if(A[i] == ch) A[i] = ' ';
}
for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
  printf("%2c", A[i]);
}
getch();
}
```

А вот код на `С++`,  который работает

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char A[10];
  int n , i;
  char sim, ch;
  cout << "Vvedite razmer ";
  cin >> n;
  cout << "Vvedute symbolu ";
  
  for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
    cin >> A[i];
  }
  for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
    cout << A[i];
  }
  cout << "\nDelete symbol ";
  cin >> sim;
  cout << "\n";
  for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
      if(A[i] == sim) A[i] = ' ';
    
  }
  for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
    cout << A[i];
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Как минимум не `scanf("%s", &ch);` а `scanf("%c", &ch);`...

Comment: Если я так делаю то он обще не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
printf("razmer ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("symbol ");

for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
    scanf(" %c", &A[i]);
}
for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
    printf("%2c", A[i]);
}
printf("\ndelite ");
scanf(" %c", &ch);
printf("\n");
for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
    if(A[i] == ch) A[i] = ' ';
}
for (i = 0;i < n;i++) {
    printf("%2c", A[i]);
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/JqeY5n